# <select> Popup Windows

Tags: html, popupwindow, buttonclick

Ok I have been searching to find something of similar but having no luck..

I want to know how you can get this code to pop up in a new window and be resized? Example: Window is 250px by 250px, No Border, No Address Bar.. Just a compact window.

This is something I have found, but not sure how I would get it to work...

```
<form action="../">
<select id="select-box" class="select" name="selectbox" size="6">
<option value="Folder1/List_1.html">1</option>
<option value="Folder2/List_2.html">2</option>
<option value="Folder3/List_3.html">3</option>
<option value="Folder4/List_4.html">4</option>
<option value="Folder5/List_5.html">5</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Open Page" onclick="ob=this.form.selectbox;window.open(ob.options[ob.selectedIndex].value)">
</form>
```

What I do know is, the data entered in the "action" is incorrect.. I just don't know how I can make it read specific folders etc... I do know if I remove "action" it then loads the pages into new tabs. But it doesn't load them into a new window..
I know nothing about this, just been playing around and reading tuts, so if you can help me, it would be appreciated.. Thanks.

Comment: You should use `<button></button>` instead of `<input type="submit" />` and use a function instead of trying to do it all in the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: I will look into that, never really heard or seen anything about, so perhaps it might be the way for me to go.. With my original select box, I had a javascript for it which worked if you just clicked the name in the box, but this didn't work on Mobiles. It had the ability to open in its own Popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to open in a popup window you need to use `"_blank"` in the `window.open()`. Then you can use the other attributes to change the size of the window. Also, there are limited things about the window that you can remove. [`window.open()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

**HTML**

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
    <select id="select-box" class="select" name="selectbox" size="6">
        <option value="Folder1/List_1.html">1</option>
        <option value="Folder2/List_2.html">2</option>
        <option value="Folder3/List_3.html">3</option>
        <option value="Folder4/List_4.html">4</option>
        <option value="Folder5/List_5.html">5</option>
    </select>
    <button onclick="popup(this.form.selectbox);">Open Page</button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
function popup(ob) {
    if (ob.selectedIndex < 0)
        return false;
    window.open(ob.options[ob.selectedIndex].value, "_blank", "height=200,width=200,menubar=no,status=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no");
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/koLw5Lms/1/)

Comment: Just to confirm this has worked, just curious if you know if this would work with Samsung Galaxy Mobile. Previous issue was, you wouldn't be able to even click the Select Box to see data.

Comment: @Trent You might want to consider making the font a little bigger and removing the `select` `size="6"` attribute. Then you should be able to select it on a mobile device.  http://jsfiddle.net/imtheman/koLw5Lms/2/